# CSS horizontal rule with content in center

Tags: html, css

Visit this link for my demonstration: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bvkjx

I want to achieve the following:

```
content:'hellooo';
```

Make this fit inside the circle without clipping / overflowing, basically re-size to fit automatically is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

`line-height:50px; /* Same height as the circle */`

and

`text-align:center;`